# "К скольки" или "ко скольки"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

"К скольки" или "ко скольки"? Как правильно?

Answer (score 9):

**Вопрос** Ко скольки или к скольки – как пишется правильно?

**Ответ**
Не стоит употреблять ни в устной, ни в письменной речи оба варианта.

На крайний случай можно написать "к скОльким часам".

Но лучше всего употреблять "к которому часу "

**Почему так?**

Сколько – это числительное местоимение, которое склоняется по падежам и зависит от существительного. Предлог к относится к дательному падежу (кому?).

В русском языке существуют следующие формы местоимения «сколько»:

сколько (именительный падеж);
скольких (родительный, винительный, предложный падежи);
скольким (дательный падеж);
сколькими (творительный падеж).
Формы «скольки» местоимения сколько не существует.

Вместо «к(ко) скольки» лексически привычней и красивей всего говорить и писать «к которому часу».

Но можно написать и "к скОльким часам". Причем ударение в слове сколько в любых формах падает на первый слог.

**Ошибочное написание** Ко скольки, к скольки.

**Примеры правильного** 
 К которому часу Вас ожидать?
К скольким часам мне следует подойти?

Answer (score 6):

К скОльким, ко скОльким.

Answer (score 2):

> "к скольки"

В любом случае - "к скОльким". Будь то время или еще что.

> если надо прийти к какому-то конкретному времени, например, к 09.15, тогда спрашивать "к которому часу?"

Да. Лучше всего именно так.
Или "к какому времени", но это уже разговорный вариант с оттенком просторечности.
Но "сколько времени" именно в таком сочетании никак не может быть употреблено. В остальных случаях можно сослаться на "сколько времени (часов) прошло с полудня/полуночи". Ответ типа "семь часов [прошло]" "пять минут третьего [часа]" вполне релевантны.
Но никак не "к сколькии [часам]".

Comment: "А в школу со скольк**и** лет берут?" - "Вам уже поздно, батенька..."

"Ваня, ты до скольк**и** считать умеешь?" - "Я, Марь Иванна, вчера до полвторого свои двойки считал, пока заснул! "

Comment: @grumant писал:

>>"А в школу со скольки лет берут?" - "Вам уже поздно, батенька..."  
"Ваня, ты до скольки считать умеешь?" - "Я, Марь Иванна, вчера до полвторого свои двойки считал, пока заснул! "    
  
А вот это примеры неграмотного употребления.

Answer (score 1):

Прежде всего "(к) ск**о**льким" - и только так. Ударение тоже должно быть на месте, хотя тут ошибка была бы менее грубая по сравнению с формой "скольки".

По поводу формы предлога смотрите тут.
["Ко" или "к"?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/32550)

Там цитата якобы с "Грамоты", не уверена, что это первоисточник, но все по делу.

> Предлог ко употребляется перед формами дательного падежа слов лев,
>   лед, лен, лоб, ложь, мох, ров, рожь, рот (с начальными ль, л, м, р +
>   согл.). Употребляется перед формой мне. Употребляется перед формами
>   дательного падежа слов весь, всякий, всяческий, вторник, второе,
>   второй, многие, многое.

Сочетание "к скольким" к числу требующих огласованной формы не относится.
Поэтому - "к скольким".