# Предлоги "ко" и "к"

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги

Недавно мне прочли целую лекцию на тему того, что говорить, например, *пойду **к** врачу* нельзя, а нужно — ***ко*** врачу.

Ни в одном ***классическом*** произведении, авторы которых владели ***настоящим*** русским языком, мне не встречалось это "КО".
Не могли бы специалисты-филологи разъяснить мне: ***откуда*** взялось это непонятное "КО"?

Answer (score 3):

По поводу употребления предлогов **К** и **КО** существуют две точки зрения:
1) предлоги различаются по смыслу;
2) предлоги различаются по фонетическим показателям.

Фонетическая теория мне кажется более убедительной по следующим причинам:
1. В толковых словарях  смысловое различие предлогов *никак не обозначено.*
2. Выражение "пойти ко врачу" просто неудобно для произношения.
3. Предлог **К** более употребителен, а **КО** мы используем в особых случаях, когда имеет место встреча согласных, неудобных для произношения.

С другой стороны, закономерность фонетической нестыковки определить достаточно сложно, например: ***ко*** мне, **ко** всему, но: ***к*** встрече.

Информация из Интернета (разные мнения):

1. http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/trudnosti/36_181
   Предлог **ко** употребляется со словом **день**  в значении приуроченности к какому-нибудь событию:
   *подарок **ко** дню рождения; фестиваль **ко** Дню строителя, концерт **ко** Дню милиции.*
   Но ср.: *относиться **к** дню рождения без энтузиазма* (нет значения приуроченности действия).
2. ttp://otvet.mail.ru/question/76513309
   Как уже отмечалось, варианты предлогов "к", "в", "с" и других с конечным гласным "о" используются для удобства произношения при стечении на стыке слов нескольких согласных подряд.
   В Вашем примере *(**ко** дню)* при использовании предлога "к" возникает сочетание "ккдн" из четырёх согласных, в котором два раза подряд повторяется согласный "к"!
   Неудивительно, что при таком труднопроизносимом сочетании "к" заменяют на "ко".

Comment: Да уж, автор, к сожалению, не ответит. Не понял "В Вашем примере (ко дню)": у автора нет такого примера, а также не понял, откуда вторая К ("ккдн").

Answer (score 2):

> откуда взялось это непонятное "КО"

Правильно: **"к врачу"**. У меня сейчас нет под рукой авторитетного источника, но если тезисно, то образование огласованной формы некоторых предлогов регулируется не столько стечением согласных, сколько закрепившимися сочетаниями. Такие формы ("*ко", "со", "во"*) были обычными на определенном этапе развития языка, но сейчас за пределами народно-поэтической речи закреплены только в отдельных случаях. Прежде всего это формы при местоимениях и местоименных существительных и числительных (*ко мне, ко всем, ко второму*). Так называемое "стечение согласных" действительно диктует (*ко рту, ко льду*) или разрешает (*"ко двору" и "к двору", но "к двойнику"*) огласованную форму, но само понятие "стечения" не так просто. Наличие вторым элементом сонорного Р или Л обычно исключает сочетание из списка стечений, требующих "огласованного" предлога (***к врачу***, к брату, к пловцу).

Полностью изложить все проблематику я не берусь даже для одного предлога, смотреть надо, наверное, у Аванесова, и ознакомится с актуальным для слогоделения принципом повышения звучности.

Answer (score 1):

Полагаю, нельзя в русском языке все сводить к правилам. Для меня лично дико не только видеть  предлог КО в сочетании с сущ. "врач", но и произносить его. Затруднений в речи при сочетании трех согласных никаких нет. В русском языке чуть ли не в каждом правиле есть исключение. Так зачем огород городить? Я полжизни проработала корректором и ни разу не встречала подобного сочетания в письменной речи.

Comment: Ваше утверждение про правило здесь не совсем уместно. Речь-то как раз о том, что подобное правило существует только чьей-то голове.

Comment: Я полжизни проработала... Вопрос не о стаже, не о профессии! Автор спрашивает: откуда взялось это непонятное КО?

Answer (score 1):

Про данные из справочников написали уже.
Что же касается практического применения: я с детства от всех слышал именно "пойти ко врачу", так и употребляю.
Но при этом: "подойти к врачу".
То есть получается разный смысл и контекст.

Кстати примерно те же мутации смыслов получаются и в справочных примерах.
Скажем, нормально услышать "пойти ко дну", но как-то правильнее по-моему звучит "ближе к дну" чем "ближе ко дну".

Моя языковая интуиция подсказывает, что "ко" применяется в более абстрактных ситуациях, тогда как "к" в более определенных, конкретных. То есть "пойти ко врачу" - это некое общее описание комплексного процесса, включающего в себя и выход из дома и поездку в поликлинику и т.д. Тогда как "подойти к врачу" описывает непосредственно процесс ходьбы в сторону врача:)

Comment: Любопытно. Вероятно, "пойти ко врачу" — это что-то местное или диалектное. Ни в сёлах, ни в городах, в которых я жил, не приходилось такого слышать.

Comment: Поставил плюс за ответ, с которым я не совсем согласен, но который, по-видимому, отражает специфику какого-то диалекта.

Answer (score 0):

Розенталь в книге "Управление в русском языке" писал:

***Ко*** употребляется:

1. Перед односложными словами, начинающимися со стечения  согласных:
   *ко дну* (ср. *к дневнику*), *ко лбу*, ср. также: *ко многому, ко многим*.
2. Перед словами *весь, всякий:* *ко всему, ко всякому*.
3. В отдельных выражениях: (быть, прийтись) *ко двору, не ко двору.*

**Грамота.ру** вносит уточнение:

Предлог ***ко*** употребляется перед формами дательного падежа слов ***лев, лёд, лён, лоб, ложь, мох, ров, рожь, рот*** (*с начальными **ль, л, м, р + согл.**).*
Употребляется перед формой ***мне*.**
Употребляется перед формами **дательного** падежа слов ***весь, всякий, всяческий, вторник, второе, второй, многие, многое*.**

Comment: Эта информация является описанием явления, но не его анализом, даже намека на какое-либо объяснение нет. Странно, что исследование на тему употребления целой группы суффиксов так и не проведено.