# Ко вторым или к вторым?

Tags: предлоги

*Первые посылали меня к/ко вторым, вторые к первым.*

Как, собственно, правильно?

Answer (score 2):

Правильно ***ко*** вторым.

Смотрите ответ tat [тут](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/32550/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%B8-%D0%BA):

> Предлог ***ко*** употребляется перед формами дательного падежа слов *лев, лёд, лён, лоб, ложь, мох, ров, рожь, рот (с начальными **ль, л, м, р + согл.**).*
>   Употребляется перед формой ***мне*.**
>   Употребляется перед формами **дательного** падежа слов *весь, всякий, всяческий, вторник, второе, **второй**, многие, многое.*

Comment: Благодарю. Действительно, интересно.