# Какой предлог выбрать: к или ко?

Tags: предлоги

Незнакомка не подпускала никого близко к вдове.
Или:
Незнакомка не подпускала никого близко ко вдове.

Comment: Оба варианта правильны. Выберите тот, который Вам самой больше нравится.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По слуху лучше: ***к вдове.***

**Пояснение**

Предлог  ***КО*** — это вариант основного предлога ***К***, поэтому требует обоснования и особого внимания. В данном случае нет видимых **причин** для использования предлога ***КО***.

Как верно отмечалось ранее **на форуме**, формы ***къ,съ, въ*** с кратким гласным "были обычными на определенном **этапе** развития языка, но сейчас за пределами народно-поэтической речи закреплены только в **отдельных** случаях".

Другими словами, это чаще всего **традиция**, в том числе в **устойчивых** сочетаниях, а иногда связано с **фонетикой** (удобным произношением).

**МАТЕРИАЛЫ ПО ТЕМЕ**

1. Большой толковый словарь.
   **КО, предлог**. Употр. вместо "к" (2.К) перед словами, начинающимися с некоторых групп согласных (например: ***ко всем, ко мне, не ко двору, ко дну, ко сну***).
2. [Информация из "Письмовника" с портала gramota.ru](https://marjulia.livejournal.com/95532.html)

**К - ко**

Предлог ко употребляется:

1. перед формами дательного падежа слов **лев, лёд, лён, лоб, ложь, мох, ров, рожь, рот: ко льву, ко лбу;**
2. перед формами дательного падежа слов **весь, всякий, всяческий, вторник, второе, второй, многие, многое:** сделать ко вторнику, ко всякому человеку, ко второму числу (но с цифрой: к 2 сентября);
3. **в устойчивых сочетаниях** со словами ко времени (в значении 'к сроку, вовремя': такие рассуждения не ко времени), (не) ко двору ('некстати': прийтись не ко двору, но: машина подъехала к двору); ко дню (в значении приуроченности к какому-либо событию, празднику: подарок ко дню рождения, но: относиться к дню рождения без энтузиазма); сочинение ко Дню Победы (но: закончить благоустройство к Дню города); в устойчивых сочетаниях со словами день, сон: пойти ко дну, отойти ко сну (лечь спать), клонит ко сну (хочется спать).
   В сочетаниях со словами **вчерашний, шов** употребляются оба предлога - к и ко: к вчерашним газетам и ко вчерашним газетам.

3. Обсуждение на форуме [Предлоги "ко" и "к"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/32550/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%B8-%D0%BA)